# Using different tape drives with different servers

Tags: backup, hp, tape

I am using HP MSL 2024 LTO 6 Fiber and backup exec 2012.

My tape library has two magazines with one tape drive. I want to have two separate backup exec software but currently using only one drive. If I add another drive, can I limit each of them to use a separate magazine? i.e., drive A use only left magazine and drive B only use right magazine.

And if so, can I make the 2 software on different servers, work with separate drives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Shared Storage Option (Called as Enterprise Server Option in BE 2012), this may be possible. Have a look at this article for more info and requirements about this option - http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO24287